# Mudando cor de botão dinamicamente no Android

Tags: android, ui

Tenho um menu, com 3 botões, e preciso mudar a cor deles de forma dinâmica em código.

Atualmente estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
mDrawable.setColorFilter (0xff0099cc, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

O que acontece é que ele aplica corretamente ao botão a cor, mas quando eu troco de activity e clico em outro botão, o primeiro botão que é ativado sempre fica com a cor como se ainda estivesse ativado.
*Esse menu está incluído nas três activitys.

Na imagem abaixo representa o que acontece, quando eu clico em outro botão, ele ativa o outro mas o primeiro permanece com a cor ainda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando muda a cor de um botão terá de restituir a cor original aos outros botões

Comment: @ramaral, mesmo quando eu troco de activity e tudo é recriado? Veja que a cor do texto Início, voltou ao normal... apenas o ícone que não...

Comment: Em principio não, caso efectivamente tudo é recriado. Teria de ver o código para saber se de facto "tudo é recriado".

Comment: Pelo o que entendi bem... você está abrindo uma activity quando o clique no botão é efetuado?

Answer (score 0):

Precisaria do código para ver como você está fazendo, mas basicamente, quando você inicia uma activity, a anterior é destruída, ou seja, esse tablayout seria destruído e recriaria um novo. Então você teria que para cada activity, setar no onCreate() as cores relacionadas, por exemplo, se você está na tela de conta, você selecionaria as cores azuis para esse (ícone e texto da conta) (Lembrando que por default, todos os ícones e textos serão brancos). Então para cada activity você setaria a cor da page que você está.

Outra forma que você poderia utilizar para setar as cores automaticamente, seria passando informações da activity anterior para a quer você deseja... essa informação seria justamente a cor do ícone e você poderia passar no momento do clique.